# R nought calculation ( SIR model)

Tags: homework, community-ecology

1 person gets bitten by 9vectors /night, the vector transmits the pathogen to 0.035 new hosts. Duration of infection: 9.5 months.What is R0?
I am struggling with this question for ages as I would  just multiply 9*0.035*9.5 to get R nought. However I was given a formula to use R0= βS0/v+µ+γ  but I don't know how to use because I don't get what I should.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: With `$R_0$`, you get $R_0$ and it looks better than "R nought"

Comment: "I don't get what I should" - what do you get? This sounds like a 'homework' question - which is fine, but you have to explain what you've attempted better so we can work out where you're going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\rzero}{\cal R_0}$

If this is a vector-borne disease we don't really have enough information to compute the full $\rzero$ value (i.e. expected number of infected vectors caused by a single infected vector in an otherwise disease-free population), but we can compute a "vector-to-host" $\rzero$ (expected number of hosts infected by a single infected vector). The biting rate seems to be superfluous information unless your "vector transmits the pathogen to 0.035 new hosts" is supposed to be "infected vector has a probability of 0.035 of transmitting disease to a host it has bitten".

What are you "supposed to get"?

The formula you've given, $\rzero = \beta S(0)/(v + \mu + \gamma)$, is more generally applied to directly transmitted diseases, where

- $\beta$ is the transmission rate (number of effective contacts per susceptible host per infected host per unit time) $\times$ probability of transmission
- $S(0)$ is the population density
- $v$ is the recovery rate
- $\mu$ is the natural mortality rate
- $\gamma$ is the disease-induced mortality rate

The 9.5 months is likely to be a host infection time (most biting vectors don't live that long).

Notation does vary somewhat, though.

For a vector-borne disease I would write $\rzero$ as

$$
\frac{m a^2 bc}{r \mu}
$$

where $m$=number of mosquitos/host; $a$=bites/time on host; $b$=mosquito to human transmission probability; $c$=human to mosquito transmission probability; $r$=human recovery rate (disease duration=$1/r$); $\mu$=mosquito mortality rate (mosquito lifespan=$1/\mu$).
[Google Books link](https://books.google.ca/books?id=XozcayyVQm8C&pg=PA70&lpg=PA70&dq=ross-macdonald+R0&source=bl&ots=o2wp8fR2cH&sig=Uybed3NeXuxwiL1JB1LEm0HP3Gg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiWztWC86jXAhWl54MKHTBSCOsQ6AEISTAE#v=onepage&q=ross-macdonald%20R0&f=false)